# .split() for getting strings in larger strings TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, split

I’m trying to make a code that splits each element into words, from the list `titles`, then appending all the words from all the titles into `word_list` for further analysis. But this doesn’t seem to work, it gets stuck on the for-loop part.

```
titles = data["headline"]

titles = titles.tolist()

word_list = []

words = []


for title in titles:
    words = titles[title].split()
    word_list.append(words)

word_list
```

I get this error, I think from `titles[title]`.

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Is there a way to make the loop work or another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `title` is not an index into `titles`, it's a value. You should use `words = title.split()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems. The first problem is that you're trying to access `titles[title]`, however, `title` is already an element of `titles`.

The second problem is that you're appending a list to `word_list`, but I think you want to use `.extend()` instead to merge the lists. This way, each word in `words` will be added to `word_list`, rather than `word_list` becoming a list of lists.

Here's what I think you want to do:

```
titles = data["headline"].tolist()

word_list = []
for title in titles:
    words = title.split()
    word_list.extend(words)

print(word_list)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379461/can-i-ask-someone-to-accept-my-answer-to-a-question-on-hold-if-they-found-it-use